# Kendo window data undefined

Tags: javascript, telerik, window, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a form, in the javascript onSubmit event i make an ajax call to load a kendo
window

Js:

```
function onSubmit(){

    var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
    window.refresh({
                    url: url
                }).open();
}
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window() _
.Modal(True) _
.Visible(False) _
.Name("window") _
.Title("Window"))
```

and this works great, but when I click on a button inside the window and go to the javascript onClick event, if I try to instantiate the window again and access `.data("kendoWindow")`, I get undefined (not in `$("#window")`).

```
function onClickButton(e){
  var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow"); //undefined in .data("kendoWindow")
      window.refresh({
        url: url
    }).open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the variable named `window` - this is the name of the global scope.

If this doesn't help, post a full runnable mcve, e.g., in a kendo dojo